# Events on openlayers overviewmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3

I'm using openlayers 3 on a simple html page, to display a map with an overviewmap.
I would like to know if it is possible to trigger events on openlayers overviewmaps, like we can do on openlayers maps.

Indeed I have features displayed on the overviewmap (**not on the map**) and I'd like to be able to select them.

I can't see anything in the API related with that.

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i was able to do it like this (getOverviewMap() has to be called on the overviewMap element) :

```
var overviewMapControl = new ol.control.OverviewMap({
    // Parameters for my overviewMap
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        overviewMapControl
    ]),
    // ... other parameters
});
```

and the event triggered :

```
overviewMapControl.getOverviewMap().on('click', function(evt) {
    overviewMapControl.getOverviewMap().forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, 
    function(feature, layer) {   
       console.log(feature.getProperties());
    });                                                                         
});
```